# Prevent Internet Explorer from Automatically Switching Windows (when Downloads are complete)

Tags: internet-explorer

To provide more detail in case the title isn't clear enough: basically, I use IE to run downloads of larger sized files in the background. The problem is that each time one of those downloads is complete IE takes it upon itself to automatically switch to the browser, effectively disrupting whatever work I'm doing in another program.
I'm wondering if there is a way to disable this 'feature' in the settings (I couldn't find anything) or to use windows to stop IE from taking control in that way.

Here are some of my system details that may be relevant:

> OS: Windows 8.1, 
> IE version: 11.0.9600.18098,
>   
> Update Version: 11.0.25

I do have and do simultaneously run other browsers (chrome, opera and firefox) at times but I'm not necessarily using them (they're also just running in the background) when IE switches the window to itself.

I've looked for a solution to this problem but couldn't find it online and I'm no t sure whether this is a problem with just this version or whether IE inherently performs this action.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found a solution for this issue.

In order to prevent IE from automatically switching you out of whatever software you are using at the time that it finishes its downloads for you, simply minimize all of the IE windows.

I've tried it on a couple of occasions and it seems to have worked for me.